# What are appropriate probes for use with a HP 54501A Osciliscope

Tags: oscilloscope, probe

I'm fairly new to hobby electronics, but when my office remodeled (I work on software in an EE lab) they were throwing out a HP 54501A scope that I was allowed to take. It didn't come with any probes, and I need to know what kind of probes I should look at acquiring. So:

Did the HP 54501A come with a default probe?

What is its part number if it exists?

Are there other compatible cheap probes out there for someone who is only currently looking at doing the simplest electronics? I am only likely doing Arduino type projects.

The scope is a 100Mz digitizing scope and the inputs read 1 M ohm = 16 pF  250V Max

Comment: There are two kinds of basic probes... Cheap ones and good ones.  Even if you have good ones, 90% of the time you might as well be putting wear & tear on 2/$32 cheap ones.  And cheap ones are much better than random pieces of wire or 50 ohm (!!) BNC patch cables pressed into service in place of damaged/missing/insufficient good ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any "classic" scope probe will probably work.  Here's one for pretty cheap http://www.adafruit.com/products/1528?gclid=CMXu85Hkj8ICFeLm7AodEEIA3Q

According to the manual the probe it came with was this guy http://www.keysight.com/en/pd-1000000970%3Aepsg%3Apro-pn-10432A/101-1m-miniature-passive-probe?cc=US&lc=eng

Depending on what you want to measure you can also make your own  with just some 50 ohm bnc cable, or by making an actual probe like this http://cromwell-intl.com/radio/probes.html

But as cheap as you can get these I'd just buy one.